# Search PSQL JSONB array of tuples

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a JSONB column "deps" like this

```
[
    [{
        "name": "A"
    }, "823"],
    [{
        "name": "B"
    }, "332"],
    [{
        "name": "B"
    }, "311"]
]
```

I want to set a column "stats" to NULL for all rows where the JSON array in the column "deps" contains a tuple with "name" "B". In the example above the column "deps" has two such tuples.
Is it possible?

The dictionary `{"name": "B"}` always comes first in the tuple.

Would the same search in this JSON be faster:

```
[{
        "id": {
            "name": "A"
        },
        "value": "823"
    }, {
        "id": {
            "name": "B"
        },
        "value": "332"
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "name": "B"
        },
        "value": "311"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the contains operator `@>` if the content has the structure of your first example

```
update the_table
   set stats = null
where deps @> '[[{"name": "B"}]]'
```

For the structure in the second example, you would need to use:

```
where deps @> '[{"id": {"name": "B"}}]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `@?` [psql JSON operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html) in combination with `jsonpath` to check if your JSONB blob contains any `{"name": "B"}` for any first value of all occurring tuples.

Here is an example with the JSONB blob from the stated question:

```sql
-- returns 'true' if any first tuple value contains an object with key "name" and value "B"
SELECT '[[{"name": "A"}, "823"], [{"name": "B"}, "332"], [{"name": "B"}, "311"]]'::JSONB @? '$[*][0].name ? (@ == "B")';
```

Now you can combine this with your `UPDATE` logic:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET stats = NULL
WHERE deps @? '$[*][0].name ? (@ == "B")';
```

Comment: or simpler, `deps @@ '$[*][0].name == "B"'`